# Manually loading apex test code coverage from sfdx command into vsCode

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, vs-code

Whenever I run tests through vsCode, the tests take very long time to complete (a single test could take up >10 min or they time out with the "Your request exceeded the time limit for processing. connection was cancelled here" error).

If I run the same tests through sfdx using the -y flag to run them synchronously, they complete in a fraction of the time.

sfdx apex run test --tests <TEST_CLASS>.<TEST_METHOD> -r tap -c -y

The problem is that I then don't have the very useful coverage overlay to visually see which lines have been ran.  I assume there are multiple ways to achieve a better testing experience:

• Manipulate the sfdx command that vsCode is issuing so that I can run the tests synchronously.

• Take the test run output from the sfdx command and load it into the code coverage overlay in vscode.

Is anyone aware of how to achieve either?

Thanks in advance